# Use for WorkItemAttribute?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, tfs

I noticed there's an attribute Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.WorkItemAttribute available in visual studio testing (I'm using VS 2010 Premium and work items with TFS 2010.)

Marking a test method with a work item number sounds handy, but does it actually do anything?  I can't tell if there's any tool support for it at all.  I set one up like this:

```
[WorkItem(25788)]
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomethingSpecificToABug()
{
    ...
```

But no magic - I thought maybe the context menu on the test in the Test Results window might offer to open the work item, or Team Explorer might have a feature to search for tests.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.workitemattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is no help either.  What is this attribute good for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to "[Software Testing with Visual Studio® 2010](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/software-testing/9780132180634)" by [Jeff Levinson](http://www.informit.com/authors/author_bio.aspx?ISBN=9780321734488) (Addison-Wesley Professional, February 2011, ISBN-10: 0-321-73448-3):

> This also means that one existing property should not be used anymore:
>   Associated Work Items. This value is not reported to the data
>   warehouse and therefore cannot be used for reporting. If you currently
>   use this property, consider associating your test with an actual Test
>   Case work item type.

So the answer is, don't use this with TFS 2010.

Answer (score 3):

WorkItem Test Method attribute is not used for associating test methods to test cases. It is typically used to associate a test method with a bug. 
A related C# example from [Code Index - How to discover ignored tests](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Code-Index-How-to-discover-e2d54475):

> When using MSTest to build your suite of unit tests, you can use the
>   attribute [Ignore] to tell the MSTest engine not to run a test instead
>   of commenting it. You may also use the attribute [WorkItem(id)] to
>   link the unit test to a bug database (such as TFS) item, so that you
>   can trace why a particular test has been marked as ignored:

```
    [Ignore]
    [WorkItem(12345)] // bug 12345 describes why this test was ignored 
    [TestMethod]
    public void IgnoredButWithWorkItemTest()
    {
        //The actual code is not important;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's to link the unit test back to a work item in TFS. I'd provide a link to more info but it seems it really is poorly documented.

I haven't used it myself but believe it can be used to generate reports on the status of work items.

Answer (score 1):

This isn´t needed anymore: in VS 2013 via [CodeLens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx)

**Find linked work items (Alt + 7)**

[image]

**Find linked code reviews (Alt + 8)**

[image]

**Find linked bugs (Alt + 9)**

[image]

**To review a test's definition, double-click the test.**

[image]

Oh! for those that cherish Lync:

**Contact the owner of an item (Shift + F10)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really do remember, that I used this Attribute before and the test results have been attached to the respective WorkItem.

However, with Visual Studio 2012, it does not work anymore, or I forgot which mechanism was actually responsible for the magic. Could it be that this only works through the build server?

Answer (score 0):

Pulling attributes from the test binary is really useful when you have a home grown test harness built for running Selenium UI unit tests.

After a test failure, I can pull the WorkItemAttribute value using System.Reflection.MemberInfo.CustomAttributes and then look up the ID with the TFS API. If the work item is a bug and it's still active, I can auto-resolve the failure to that bug. In this manner, I can run the failing test every day and automatically resolve the failure to reduce randomization.