# how to hyperlink to a TFS item from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, hyperlink

Is there a way in visual studio to automatically hyperlink directly to a bug/TestCase/WorkItem?

For example, I might have a code comment like this:

```
//Fix for TFS bug number 12345
```

I want visual studio to recognize that 12345 is a bug number and automatically give me a hyperlink to that bug number.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you *can* do is:

- Put the full work item URL (e.g.:
  `http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_workitems/edit/12345`)
- Use [`WorkItemAttribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7366495/147211) in test classes
- Convince your boss to buy you a VS 2013 Ultimate with [CodeLens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx)...